# Set cursor in middle of EditText if not null else in the starting

Tags: android, android-edittext

In one of my `edit text`, when I'm writing I want the text to be witten in middle & If I delete the text or the text.length = 0, then I want the cursor to be on starting (left).
For this I'm trying in the

I was thinking of doing it with `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL & Gravity.NO_GRAVITY`, in my `TextChangedListener's afterTextChanged()`. But it is not working.

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You mind middle of the edittext or middle of the text inside edittext?

Answer (score 1):

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                   @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                    int after) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                @Override
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           if(s.length()>0){
                                edittext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                             }
                             else{
                                  edittext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                             }
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                @Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                        int after) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    ed.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                }
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())) {
    editText.setSelection(0);
}else{
   //Sets the cursor position of the edittext
    editText.setSelection(POSITION_YOU_WANT);
}
```